# Phonegap - Android Splash Screen - Centre Logo

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Can anybody advise me on how to setup a splash screen to work cross resolution?
I have tried re-sizing a png file to different dimensions and placing the image in the ldpi,mdpi,hdpi folders, but the image still looks stretched/squashed depending on the device.

Is there a way to place a logo centre of the screen with a white background, i'm happy to use one size of logo even as long as it sits in the middle and looks ok¬?

Does anyone have any advice?
Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of/considered using a 9 patch version of the logo? A nine patch image allows you to define areas of an image which can be stretched. If you create your logo png file with a white background and then set the white area as stretchable it will then fill your container nicely but the logo part of the image will not distort at all.

Comment: cheers man - your advice and this tutorial - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html solved my issue!

Comment: Don't use a 9-patch if you are using Phonegap to develop your app. They don't support 9-patch yet. http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/does_phonegap_build_support_the_use_of_9_patch_images

Answer (score 0):

In your android-sdk directory, under the tools subdirectory, execute a tool called draw9patch

```
./draw9patch
```

Drag your image in there. Use the left view for drawing pixels on the top and left sides. Use the right view for inspecting how your image will stretch on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer has EVERYTHING to do with the stretchy areas of your 9patch image.  I found the answer by pinging the github question.  A user sent me to another discussion where someone had cracked it.

The main issue is that most 9patch tutorials explain how to stretch buttons, but none detail how to center an image.

Look for the green/blue/red image a little more than half way through the discussion.

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/stretched_9_patch_splash_screens_android

The key for me was to look at the edges.  It's really hard to see (for me at least), but you can barely make out the black marks along the edge that define the stretchy areas.  top has 2 small areas (on the green), left has 2 small (on the green), bottom has one long (on the blue), right has one long (on the blue).

Consequently, I find this one image (as hard as it is to see the lines) a better instruction on how 9patch works than all of the tutorials I've watched.