# Android - PhoneGap - set splash screen not to stretch

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Is their any way to alter the android/phonegap setting so that it doesnt autostretch the splash screen?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Do you mean the HTML?  If yes try use the view port and adjust your CSS

Comment: Is this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166895/phonegap-android-splash-screen-centre-logo ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of a splash screen i used a local html page with a timed auto redirect, the put a background on and centered the logo in a div. then it works on any screen.
easiest way i found